# QProcess call write function failure

Tags: qt, qprocess

I need call QProcess to start up xterm ,after that I should send some data
to it .
why those code can't run correctly?

```
QProcess proc;
proc.start("xterm");
proc.waitForStarted();
proc.write("ls\n");
proc.waitForFinished();
proc.waitForBytesWritten();
qDebug()<<proc.readAllStandardOutput();//output: nothing
qDebug()<<proc.errorString();//output: "write error"
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Most of the functions you are calling have return values. How about checking those return values and finding what goes wrong?

Comment: I already tried that ,anything just fine but last statement

Comment: what do you mean "can't run correctly"? Does it hang? Or doesn't print anything in debug stream? I don't see a reason why xterm should end its job, so probably you code hangs on `proc.waitForFinished();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you try to do here. Your code does not make sense: you can't send xterm 'some data' (looks like you want it to execute some command for you, here *ls*) to its standard input.

If you want the output of *ls*, simply do this:

```
QProcess proc;
proc.start("ls");
proc.waitForFinished();
qDebug() << proc.readAllStandardOutput();
```

If you want an interpreter running in the background, that you can send commands for it to execute (like a shell) you may do something like:

```
QProcess proc;
proc.start("/bin/sh");
proc.waitForStarted();
Q_FOREACH( QString cmd, QStringList() << "ls" << "date" << "echo test" )
{
    proc.write((cmd + "\n").toLocal8Bit());
    proc.waitForReadyRead();
    qDebug() << proc.readAllStandardOutput().split('\n');
}
proc.write("exit\n");
proc.waitForFinished();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ,sir. I know how to call command directly, what I really need is to call qemu in console , after qemu initialized       I should type in some infomation(using QProcess?) like user and password . The real problem here is why I can't send data to xterm? sorry for my english ,English is not my mother tongue

Comment: I don't know anything about qemu but maybe you should have a look at the *Getting data in/out of the emulator* section of [this](http://landley.net/aboriginal/presentation.html) doc. Apparently you can do stuff like connect the simulated serial port to quemu's stdin/stdout and then communicate with that like with the shell above. I don't see xterm anywhere in that picture, though. It might very well, that what you try to do is not possible. I suggest to change the title of your question to something more descriptive like 'How to remote control qemu from an external process?".

Comment: Thanks again ,you already help me a lot. Anyway , I still can't send data to xterm ,I will study your doc. I tried `proc.start("sh -c \"echo password | sudo -S command\" ")` . It can works for me but not the best solution . I will keep in qustion it .

Comment: Your welcome. I still don't understand what you try to do. What does xterm and sudo and qemu have to do with each other? I think you should try to describe what you really try do to here (and change the question title to be more descriptive).